# QField Sync v3.2.0 Photo Naming not available

Tags: qfield, photos, qfieldsync

I have QFieldSync 3.2.0 installed, but do not see the 'Photo Naming Tab' in Project Configuration that was provided in 3.1.8.

Has this been removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only working with QGIS 3.14 onwards i think

Comment: thanks, that'll be it